# Removing datatypes from literals in SPARQL results

Tags: java, rdf, sparql, jena, semantic-web

I'm querying an OWL ontology using SPARQL, but the results show links as well as data.  I only want the data.  How can I remove the link and show on the data?  The output I'm getting is:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Email                                           | ind              | ind1                                               |
===========================================================================================================================
| "5"^^<http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#decimal> | my:HotelCityPark | "Hotel"^^<http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#string> |
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

The output I desire is (note that parts like `^^<http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#decimal>` are no longer present.

```
---------------------------------
| Email | ind           | ind1  |
=================================
| 5     | HotelCityPark | Hotel |
---------------------------------
```

Here is my Java code and my OWL ontology:

```java
class jena_testing
    {  public static void main(String[] args) {

            String filename="modified2.owl";
            Model model=ModelFactory.createDefaultModel();
            OntModel model1=ModelFactory.createOntologyModel(OntModelSpec.OWL_DL_MEM,model);

            try
            {
                File file=new File(filename);
                FileInputStream reader=new FileInputStream(file);
                model.read(reader,null);

                String query1="PREFIX rdfs: <http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#>"+
                    "PREFIX rdf: <http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#>"+
                        "PREFIX my: <http://www.semanticweb.org/rohit/ontologies/2014/4/untitled-ontology-20#>"+
                        "SELECT ?Email ?ind ?ind1"+
                        " WHERE {"+
                         " ?ind rdf:type my:Accomodation ."+
                          "?ind my:hasStarRating ?Email."+
                          "?ind my:hasType ?ind1."+
                        "FILTER regex(str(?ind),'HotelCityPark')"+
                        "}";
                com.hp.hpl.jena.query.Query query=QueryFactory.create(query1);
                QueryExecution exe=QueryExecutionFactory.create(query, model1);
                ResultSet RES=exe.execSelect();
                ResultSetFormatter.out(System.out, RES, query);
            }catch(Exception e)
            {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
```

```xml
<?xml version="1.0"?>


<!DOCTYPE rdf:RDF [
    <!ENTITY owl "http://www.w3.org/2002/07/owl#" >
    <!ENTITY xsd "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#" >
    <!ENTITY rdfs "http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#" >
    <!ENTITY rdf "http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#" >
    <!ENTITY untitled-ontology-20 "http://www.semanticweb.org/rohit/ontologies/2014/4/untitled-ontology-20#" >
]>


<rdf:RDF xmlns="http://www.semanticweb.org/rohit/ontologies/2014/4/untitled-ontology-20#"
     xml:base="http://www.semanticweb.org/rohit/ontologies/2014/4/untitled-ontology-20"
     xmlns:rdfs="http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#"
     xmlns:owl="http://www.w3.org/2002/07/owl#"
     xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#"
     xmlns:rdf="http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#"
     xmlns:untitled-ontology-20="http://www.semanticweb.org/rohit/ontologies/2014/4/untitled-ontology-20#">
    <owl:Ontology rdf:about="http://www.semanticweb.org/rohit/ontologies/2014/4/untitled-ontology-20"/>



    <!-- 
    ///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    //
    // Data properties
    //
    ///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
     -->




    <!-- http://www.semanticweb.org/rohit/ontologies/2014/4/untitled-ontology-20#hasLatitude -->

    <owl:DatatypeProperty rdf:about="&untitled-ontology-20;hasLatitude"/>



    <!-- http://www.semanticweb.org/rohit/ontologies/2014/4/untitled-ontology-20#hasLongitude -->

    <owl:DatatypeProperty rdf:about="&untitled-ontology-20;hasLongitude"/>



    <!-- http://www.semanticweb.org/rohit/ontologies/2014/4/untitled-ontology-20#hasStarRating -->

    <owl:DatatypeProperty rdf:about="&untitled-ontology-20;hasStarRating"/>



    <!-- http://www.semanticweb.org/rohit/ontologies/2014/4/untitled-ontology-20#hasStreet -->

    <owl:DatatypeProperty rdf:about="&untitled-ontology-20;hasStreet"/>



    <!-- http://www.semanticweb.org/rohit/ontologies/2014/4/untitled-ontology-20#hasType -->

    <owl:DatatypeProperty rdf:about="&untitled-ontology-20;hasType"/>



    <!-- 
    ///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    //
    // Classes
    //
    ///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
     -->




    <!-- http://www.semanticweb.org/rohit/ontologies/2014/4/untitled-ontology-20#Accomodation -->

    <owl:Class rdf:about="&untitled-ontology-20;Accomodation"/>



    <!-- http://www.semanticweb.org/rohit/ontologies/2014/4/untitled-ontology-20#Attractions -->

    <owl:Class rdf:about="&untitled-ontology-20;Attractions"/>



    <!-- http://www.semanticweb.org/rohit/ontologies/2014/4/untitled-ontology-20#Restuarants -->

    <owl:Class rdf:about="&untitled-ontology-20;Restuarants"/>



    <!-- 
    ///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    //
    // Individuals
    //
    ///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
     -->




    <!-- http://www.semanticweb.org/rohit/ontologies/2014/4/untitled-ontology-20#AkkalkotSwamiSamarthMaharaj_temple -->

    <owl:NamedIndividual rdf:about="&untitled-ontology-20;AkkalkotSwamiSamarthMaharaj_temple">
        <rdf:type rdf:resource="&untitled-ontology-20;Attractions"/>
    </owl:NamedIndividual>



    <!-- http://www.semanticweb.org/rohit/ontologies/2014/4/untitled-ontology-20#Ambassador_Executive -->

    <owl:NamedIndividual rdf:about="&untitled-ontology-20;Ambassador_Executive">
        <rdf:type rdf:resource="&untitled-ontology-20;Accomodation"/>
        <hasStarRating rdf:datatype="&xsd;decimal">3</hasStarRating>
        <hasType rdf:datatype="&xsd;string">Hotel</hasType>
    </owl:NamedIndividual>



    <!-- http://www.semanticweb.org/rohit/ontologies/2014/4/untitled-ontology-20#BalajiSarovarPremier -->

    <owl:NamedIndividual rdf:about="&untitled-ontology-20;BalajiSarovarPremier">
        <rdf:type rdf:resource="&untitled-ontology-20;Accomodation"/>
        <hasStarRating rdf:datatype="&xsd;decimal">3.5</hasStarRating>
        <hasType rdf:datatype="&xsd;string">Hotel</hasType>
    </owl:NamedIndividual>



    <!-- http://www.semanticweb.org/rohit/ontologies/2014/4/untitled-ontology-20#BhagwatBigCinemas -->

    <owl:NamedIndividual rdf:about="&untitled-ontology-20;BhagwatBigCinemas">
        <rdf:type rdf:resource="&untitled-ontology-20;Attractions"/>
    </owl:NamedIndividual>



    <!-- http://www.semanticweb.org/rohit/ontologies/2014/4/untitled-ontology-20#Bhuikotfort -->

    <owl:NamedIndividual rdf:about="&untitled-ontology-20;Bhuikotfort">
        <rdf:type rdf:resource="&untitled-ontology-20;Attractions"/>
    </owl:NamedIndividual>



    <!-- http://www.semanticweb.org/rohit/ontologies/2014/4/untitled-ontology-20#DhruvaHotel -->

    <owl:NamedIndividual rdf:about="&untitled-ontology-20;DhruvaHotel">
        <rdf:type rdf:resource="&untitled-ontology-20;Accomodation"/>
        <hasStarRating rdf:datatype="&xsd;decimal">3</hasStarRating>
        <hasType rdf:datatype="&xsd;string">Hotel</hasType>
    </owl:NamedIndividual>



    <!-- http://www.semanticweb.org/rohit/ontologies/2014/4/untitled-ontology-20#Durga_Mangesh_Garden_Restuarant -->

    <owl:NamedIndividual rdf:about="&untitled-ontology-20;Durga_Mangesh_Garden_Restuarant">
        <rdf:type rdf:resource="&untitled-ontology-20;Restuarants"/>
    </owl:NamedIndividual>



    <!-- http://www.semanticweb.org/rohit/ontologies/2014/4/untitled-ontology-20#GreatIndianBustardSancturay -->

    <owl:NamedIndividual rdf:about="&untitled-ontology-20;GreatIndianBustardSancturay">
        <rdf:type rdf:resource="&untitled-ontology-20;Attractions"/>
    </owl:NamedIndividual>



    <!-- http://www.semanticweb.org/rohit/ontologies/2014/4/untitled-ontology-20#HotelCityPark -->

    <owl:NamedIndividual rdf:about="&untitled-ontology-20;HotelCityPark">
        <rdf:type rdf:resource="&untitled-ontology-20;Accomodation"/>
        <hasStarRating rdf:datatype="&xsd;decimal">5</hasStarRating>
        <hasType rdf:datatype="&xsd;string">Hotelcitypark</hasType>
    </owl:NamedIndividual>



    <!-- http://www.semanticweb.org/rohit/ontologies/2014/4/untitled-ontology-20#HotelLotus -->

    <owl:NamedIndividual rdf:about="&untitled-ontology-20;HotelLotus">
        <rdf:type rdf:resource="&untitled-ontology-20;Accomodation"/>
        <hasStarRating rdf:datatype="&xsd;decimal">3</hasStarRating>
        <hasType rdf:datatype="&xsd;string">Hotel</hasType>
    </owl:NamedIndividual>



    <!-- http://www.semanticweb.org/rohit/ontologies/2014/4/untitled-ontology-20#HotelNila -->

    <owl:NamedIndividual rdf:about="&untitled-ontology-20;HotelNila">
        <rdf:type rdf:resource="&untitled-ontology-20;Accomodation"/>
        <hasStarRating rdf:datatype="&xsd;decimal">1.2</hasStarRating>
        <hasType rdf:datatype="&xsd;string">Hotel</hasType>
    </owl:NamedIndividual>



    <!-- http://www.semanticweb.org/rohit/ontologies/2014/4/untitled-ontology-20#HotelTripursundari -->

    <owl:NamedIndividual rdf:about="&untitled-ontology-20;HotelTripursundari">
        <rdf:type rdf:resource="&untitled-ontology-20;Accomodation"/>
        <hasStarRating rdf:datatype="&xsd;decimal">1.6</hasStarRating>
        <hasType rdf:datatype="&xsd;string">Hotel</hasType>
    </owl:NamedIndividual>



    <!-- http://www.semanticweb.org/rohit/ontologies/2014/4/untitled-ontology-20#HotelVaishnavi -->

    <owl:NamedIndividual rdf:about="&untitled-ontology-20;HotelVaishnavi">
        <rdf:type rdf:resource="&untitled-ontology-20;Accomodation"/>
        <hasStarRating rdf:datatype="&xsd;decimal">4.5</hasStarRating>
        <hasType rdf:datatype="&xsd;string">Hotel</hasType>
    </owl:NamedIndividual>



    <!-- http://www.semanticweb.org/rohit/ontologies/2014/4/untitled-ontology-20#KRAVINGS-THE-FOOD-WORLD -->

    <owl:NamedIndividual rdf:about="&untitled-ontology-20;KRAVINGS-THE-FOOD-WORLD">
        <rdf:type rdf:resource="&untitled-ontology-20;Restuarants"/>
    </owl:NamedIndividual>



    <!-- http://www.semanticweb.org/rohit/ontologies/2014/4/untitled-ontology-20#Kamat -->

    <owl:NamedIndividual rdf:about="&untitled-ontology-20;Kamat">
        <rdf:type rdf:resource="&untitled-ontology-20;Restuarants"/>
    </owl:NamedIndividual>



    <!-- http://www.semanticweb.org/rohit/ontologies/2014/4/untitled-ontology-20#NikitaPurVeg -->

    <owl:NamedIndividual rdf:about="&untitled-ontology-20;NikitaPurVeg">
        <rdf:type rdf:resource="&untitled-ontology-20;Restuarants"/>
    </owl:NamedIndividual>



    <!-- http://www.semanticweb.org/rohit/ontologies/2014/4/untitled-ontology-20#Pandurang_temple -->

    <owl:NamedIndividual rdf:about="&untitled-ontology-20;Pandurang_temple">
        <rdf:type rdf:resource="&untitled-ontology-20;Attractions"/>
    </owl:NamedIndividual>



    <!-- http://www.semanticweb.org/rohit/ontologies/2014/4/untitled-ontology-20#Parasnath_Jain_Temple -->

    <owl:NamedIndividual rdf:about="&untitled-ontology-20;Parasnath_Jain_Temple">
        <rdf:type rdf:resource="&untitled-ontology-20;Attractions"/>
    </owl:NamedIndividual>



    <!-- http://www.semanticweb.org/rohit/ontologies/2014/4/untitled-ontology-20#PrathamHotel -->

    <owl:NamedIndividual rdf:about="&untitled-ontology-20;PrathamHotel">
        <rdf:type rdf:resource="&untitled-ontology-20;Accomodation"/>
        <hasStarRating rdf:datatype="&xsd;decimal">1.6</hasStarRating>
        <hasType rdf:datatype="&xsd;string">Hotel</hasType>
    </owl:NamedIndividual>



    <!-- http://www.semanticweb.org/rohit/ontologies/2014/4/untitled-ontology-20#RevanSiddeshwar_temple -->

    <owl:NamedIndividual rdf:about="&untitled-ontology-20;RevanSiddeshwar_temple">
        <rdf:type rdf:resource="&untitled-ontology-20;Attractions"/>
    </owl:NamedIndividual>



    <!-- http://www.semanticweb.org/rohit/ontologies/2014/4/untitled-ontology-20#RiteshHotel -->

    <owl:NamedIndividual rdf:about="&untitled-ontology-20;RiteshHotel">
        <rdf:type rdf:resource="&untitled-ontology-20;Accomodation"/>
        <hasStarRating rdf:datatype="&xsd;decimal">3.5</hasStarRating>
        <hasType rdf:datatype="&xsd;string">Hotel1</hasType>
    </owl:NamedIndividual>



    <!-- http://www.semanticweb.org/rohit/ontologies/2014/4/untitled-ontology-20#Rukmini_temple -->

    <owl:NamedIndividual rdf:about="&untitled-ontology-20;Rukmini_temple">
        <rdf:type rdf:resource="&untitled-ontology-20;Attractions"/>
    </owl:NamedIndividual>



    <!-- http://www.semanticweb.org/rohit/ontologies/2014/4/untitled-ontology-20#Shivparvati_International_Hotel -->

    <owl:NamedIndividual rdf:about="&untitled-ontology-20;Shivparvati_International_Hotel">
        <rdf:type rdf:resource="&untitled-ontology-20;Accomodation"/>
        <hasStarRating rdf:datatype="&xsd;decimal">4</hasStarRating>
        <hasType rdf:datatype="&xsd;string">Hotel</hasType>
    </owl:NamedIndividual>



    <!-- http://www.semanticweb.org/rohit/ontologies/2014/4/untitled-ontology-20#ShriSiddheshwar_temple -->

    <owl:NamedIndividual rdf:about="&untitled-ontology-20;ShriSiddheshwar_temple">
        <rdf:type rdf:resource="&untitled-ontology-20;Attractions"/>
    </owl:NamedIndividual>



    <!-- http://www.semanticweb.org/rohit/ontologies/2014/4/untitled-ontology-20#Sips_and_Bites -->

    <owl:NamedIndividual rdf:about="&untitled-ontology-20;Sips_and_Bites">
        <rdf:type rdf:resource="&untitled-ontology-20;Restuarants"/>
    </owl:NamedIndividual>



    <!-- http://www.semanticweb.org/rohit/ontologies/2014/4/untitled-ontology-20#Spice_n_Ice -->

    <owl:NamedIndividual rdf:about="&untitled-ontology-20;Spice_n_Ice">
        <rdf:type rdf:resource="&untitled-ontology-20;Restuarants"/>
        <hasStarRating rdf:datatype="&xsd;decimal">3.5</hasStarRating>
    </owl:NamedIndividual>



    <!-- http://www.semanticweb.org/rohit/ontologies/2014/4/untitled-ontology-20#Srikamal_International_Hotel -->

    <owl:NamedIndividual rdf:about="&untitled-ontology-20;Srikamal_International_Hotel">
        <rdf:type rdf:resource="&untitled-ontology-20;Accomodation"/>
        <hasStarRating rdf:datatype="&xsd;decimal">4.8</hasStarRating>
        <hasType rdf:datatype="&xsd;string">Hotel</hasType>
    </owl:NamedIndividual>



    <!-- http://www.semanticweb.org/rohit/ontologies/2014/4/untitled-ontology-20#Supraja_Pav_Bhaji -->

    <owl:NamedIndividual rdf:about="&untitled-ontology-20;Supraja_Pav_Bhaji">
        <rdf:type rdf:resource="&untitled-ontology-20;Restuarants"/>
    </owl:NamedIndividual>



    <!-- http://www.semanticweb.org/rohit/ontologies/2014/4/untitled-ontology-20#SuryaInternational -->

    <owl:NamedIndividual rdf:about="&untitled-ontology-20;SuryaInternational">
        <rdf:type rdf:resource="&untitled-ontology-20;Accomodation"/>
        <hasStarRating rdf:datatype="&xsd;decimal">5</hasStarRating>
        <hasType rdf:datatype="&xsd;string">Hotel</hasType>
    </owl:NamedIndividual>



    <!-- http://www.semanticweb.org/rohit/ontologies/2014/4/untitled-ontology-20#Temptations -->

    <owl:NamedIndividual rdf:about="&untitled-ontology-20;Temptations">
        <rdf:type rdf:resource="&untitled-ontology-20;Restuarants"/>
    </owl:NamedIndividual>
</rdf:RDF>
```

Comment: Your question is unclear as written, you say you want the output in a different format but don't give an example of the desired output.  Please edit your question to include this as otherwise your question is unanswerable

Comment: i will give the required out put format at the end

Comment: Is this a course work question?

Comment: no i am doing project in that problem is occured

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You may want to become a bit more familiar with some of the concepts of RDF. The W3C's [RDF Primer](http://www.w3.org/TR/2004/REC-rdf-primer-20040210/) might be a good starting point.  I say this because the way that you're referring to your results suggests some unfamiliarity with RDF.  Let's take a look at them. In the results that you've shown, you're getting these values back:

```
"5"^^<http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#decimal>
my:HotelCityPark
"Hotel"^^<http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#string>
```

The first is the literal 5 with datatype xsd:decimal.  That's a number.  In RDF 1.0, literals are either plain literals (just a string), language tagged strings (a string with a language tag), or a datatyped literal (a string (lexical form) and datatype).  Literals are what you use to represent concrete data.  `"5"^^xsd:decimal` is very specific about what it is.    You *can* extract the lexical part of the datatyped literal to be left with the plain literal `"5"`, but note that that's no longer a number.  If you want a Java number, it'd be better to process to the literal and get its interpreted value.

The second is a URI that's been abbreviated as `my:HotelCityPark`.  Based on your prefix, that's the URI `http://www.semanticweb.org/rohit/ontologies/2014/4/untitled-ontology-20#HotelCityPark`.  URIs are used as identifiers in RDF.  You *can* cast that URI to a plain literal, to get `"http://www.semanticweb.org/rohit/ontologies/2014/4/untitled-ontology-20#HotelCityPark"`, and then do some string manipulation to remove everything up to and including the `#`, to be left with the plain literal `"HotelCityPark"`.

The third is a datatyped literal (with the datatype `xsd:string`).  Just like with the first, you can extract its lexical form to be left with the plain literal `"Hotel"`, and that doesn't really lose much information.  (In RDF 1.1, there are no plain literals; strings without an explicit datatype are implicitly typed with `xsd:string`.)

The values you requested

```
5
HotelCityPark
Hotel
```

don't really have enough information to tell us *what* kind of data you want. Are those supposed to be strings?  If so, then you should use

```
"5"
"HotelCityPark"
"Hotel"
```

If you want the first to be a number, you could also cast it as an `xsd:integer`, because literals of the form  `"5"^^xsd:integer` are often written as `5`.  The Turtle and N3 syntaxes support this, for instance.

You can do the casting with `xsd:integer`, string extraction with the `str` function, and removing the `my:` prefix using the `strafter` function.  Thus you'd have a query like this:

```sql
prefix xsd: <http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#>
prefix my: <http://www.semanticweb.org/rohit/ontologies/2014/4/untitled-ontology-20#>

select ?Email ?ind ?ind1 where {
   #-- The values block just binds ?_Email, ?_ind, and ?_ind1 
   #-- to the original output that you were getting.  You'd still
   #-- have your original query text here.
   values (?_Email ?_ind ?_ind1) {
     ("5"^^xsd:decimal my:HotelCityPark "Hotel"^^xsd:string)
   }

   bind( xsd:integer(?_Email) as ?Email )
   bind( strafter(str(?_ind),str(my:)) as ?ind  )
   bind( str(?_ind1) as ?ind1 )
}
```

```
-------------------------------------
| Email | ind             | ind1    |
=====================================
| 5     | "HotelCityPark" | "Hotel" |
-------------------------------------
```

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/52671/discussion-between-fanky-and-joshua-taylor)

Answer (score 0):

You should use [BIND](http://www.w3.org/TR/sparql11-query/#bind) with casting using [XPath Constructor](http://www.w3.org/TR/sparql11-query/#FunctionMapping)

Comment: i am understand can you explain more how can i apply in this example thanks

Answer (score 0):

In terms of Literals, the following approach worked for me:

```
SELECT (str(?hotel) as ?hotelstr) ...
```